# Minecraft, server crashes on mob spawn 1.9

Tags: java, recursion, minecraft

The code I am using to spawn and edit the zombies is as follows:

```
    double strength = (int) (((wave * 100) + 50) / 50);
    Location location = new Location(loc.getLocation().getWorld(), loc.getLocation().getBlockX(), loc.getLocation().getBlockY(), loc.getLocation().getBlockZ());
    location.add(0.5, 0, 0.5);
    Zombie zomb = (Zombie) location.getWorld().spawnEntity(location, EntityType.ZOMBIE);
    zomb.setBaby(false);
    setFollowDistance(zomb);
    setTotalHealth(zomb, strength);
    zomb.setHealth(strength <= 20D ? strength : 20D);
```

But whenever this runs and a zombie spawns, the server will register this and spawn the zombie in the right place. But when it does, it will freeze the zombie and then the server will crash.
Thanks.

Comment: Usually its good to start by debugging where the code is crashing. This could be as simple as a log file you write to after each step so you know what steps it completed.

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment yet but try to take this as one and a possible answer)

According to my knowledge, you can't spawn entities with more than 2048 HP, that causes a server error (and maybe a crash on recent versions).